# how to join this 4 tableview correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I want to combine these 4 tables under the results so the table will be like recap, data when I join the table  that should be a tanggal field with the name novi irawati there are 2 different dates that are dates in the december and january months, 
when I have made it turned ou   t so the error in the date turns out that the december month is all in novi irawati is a solution? beg for his help

Table laporan_totalgaji

```
nip    nama            jabatan              tanggal        tahun_masuk   gaji_pokok  total_tunjangan
10010   Muhammad Hayyi  Pimpinan             2019-12-15    2014-03-07        1425000    6669000
10011   Rifyal Ainul Yaqin  Ka Mantri        2019-12-16    2015-03-19   920000       4889200
10016   Novi Irawati    Kasir                2019-12-19    2016-04-18   650000       3075000
10019   Abdul Muik      Mantri               2019-12-20    2017-08-04   525000       4245000
10015   Alfan           Ka Mantri            2019-12-20    2017-03-10  850000       4889200
10017   Romiatul Jamil  Staff Admin          2019-12-21    2017-02-09   525000     2455000
10012   Misbahul Munir  Ka Mantri            2019-12-21    2015-09-28   920000     4889200
10018   Fidatul Hasanah Staff Admin          2019-12-21    2017-03-12   525000     2455000 
10013   Ari Arif Sholeh Ka Mantri            2019-12-21    2015-03-08   920000     4889200
10016   Novi Irawati    Kasir                2020-01-31    2016-04-18   650000     3075000
```

table sum_potongan

```
nip        nama            total_tunjangan
10010   Muhammad Hayyi  6669000
10011   Rifyal Ainul Yaqin  4889200
10012   Misbahul Munir  4889200
10013   Ari Arif Sholeh 4889200
10014   Sopantoni Hendri C  4889200
10015   Alfan   4889200
10016   Novi Irawati    3075000
10017   Romiatul Jamil  2455000
10018   Fidatul Hasanah 2455000
10019   Abdul Muik  4245000
10020   Supyan Bariki   4245000
10021   Imam Baihaki    4245000
10022   Ahmad Andika    4245000
10023   Ahmad Jufri 4245000
10024   Sulaiman Ali Farizi 4245000
```

table sum_potongan

```
nip        nama            total_potongan
10010   Muhammad Hayyi  242500
10011   Rifyal Ainul Yaqin  234000
10012   Misbahul Munir  234000
10013   Ari Arif Sholeh 234000
10014   Sopantoni Hendri C  234000
10015   Alfan   234000
10016   Novi Irawati    230500
10017   Romiatul Jamil  228500
10018   Fidatul Hasanah 228500
10019   Abdul Muik  227500
10020   Supyan Bariki   227500
10021   Imam Baihaki    227500
10022   Ahmad Andika    227500
10023   Ahmad Jufri 227500
10024   Sulaiman Ali Farizi 227500
10025   Andy Rachman    234000
10027   Tony Stark  234000
10028   Natasha 228500
```

table sum_potonganabsen

```
    nip        nama          tanggal                 total_denda
   10010    Muhammad Hayyi  2019-12-15               0
   10011    Rifyal Ainul Yaqin  2019-12-16           0
   10012    Misbahul Munir  2019-12-20               0
   10013    Ari Arif Sholeh 2019-12-20                  0
   10014    Sopantoni Hendri C  2019-12-20              0
   10015    Alfan           2019-12-20                        0
   10016    Novi Irawati    2020-01-03                37500
   10016    Novi Irawati    2019-12-19                100000
   10017    Romiatul Jamil  2019-12-20                0
   10018    Fidatul Hasanah 2019-12-20                0
   10019    Abdul Muik  2019-12-20                    0
```

my query

```
select  laporan_totalgaji.nip,
   laporan_totalgaji.nama,
   laporan_totalgaji.jabatan,
   laporan_totalgaji.tanggal,
   laporan_totalgaji.gaji_pokok,
   laporan_totalgaji.total_tunjangan,
   (laporan_totalgaji.gaji_pokok + laporan_totalgaji.total_tunjangan) as gaji_kotor,
    (sp.total_potongan) as total_potongan,s.total_potonganabsen,((laporan_totalgaji.gaji_pokok + 
       laporan_totalgaji.total_tunjangan)-(sp.total_potongan+ s.total_potonganabsen)) as gaji_bersih
    from laporan_totalgaji
     inner join sum_tunjangan st on laporan_totalgaji.nip = st.nip
     inner join sum_potongan sp on laporan_totalgaji.nip = sp.nip
      inner join sum_potonganabsen s on laporan_totalgaji.nip = s.nip
      group by laporan_totalgaji.nip,
         laporan_totalgaji.nama,
        laporan_totalgaji.jabatan,
        laporan_totalgaji.gaji_pokok,
        laporan_totalgaji.total_tunjangan,
        (laporan_totalgaji.gaji_pokok + laporan_totalgaji.total_tunjangan),
        (sp.total_potongan),
         s.total_potonganabsen,((laporan_totalgaji.gaji_pokok + laporan_totalgaji.total_tunjangan)- 
         (sp.total_potongan+s.total_potonganabsen))
```

query result

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDUzc.png)

result i want
[image]

Comment: Lee, You join condition is at fault. You are joining on nip value which is same for both rows, So DB is free to pick any date it wants. How your end result should look alike. Which date you want on the result.

Comment: wait i will edit

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is NEVER appropriate

Comment: so what must i do?

Comment: the result i want is field nama novi irawati have 2 diffrent date in december and january but my query she just show december

Answer (score 1):

For the last join, try:

```
inner join sum_potonganabsen s on laporan_totalgaji.nip = s.nip
                               and laporan_totalgaji.tangal = s.tangal
```